# Matlab newbie- reasonable way to save different-sized data

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of data where each row has several datetimes and an employee id (and the same ids will repeat in different rows). I need to evaluate the datetimes by employee, so I want to get the relevant data together for processing afterward.  I'm new to Matlab and don't have a great sense of what's best for this (struct array, cell array, individual arrays, etc). Note: I do know up front how many employees I'll be evaluating, but they will have different numbers of datetimes, so a matrix is probably wrong.

Right now I loop through the rows of my matrix and check the user column, and I'd like to be able to save the datetimes from that row into a place for that user (and append if there are already some there)

```
data_matrix = [1,735724.291666667,735724.322916667,735724.343750000,5;
    2,735724.331250000,735724.340277778,735724.371527778,18;
    3,735724.402083333,735724.420833333,735724.445833333,18;
    4,735724.411111111,735724.465277778,735724.515972222,42;
    5,735724.412500000,735724.433333333,735724.459027778,8;
    6,735724.425000000,735724.519444444,735724.552777778,5;
    7,735724.431250000,735724.455555556,735724.482638889,18;
    8,735724.438888889,735724.486805556,735724.495833333,8;
    9,735724.531944444,735724.545138889,735724.581250000,18;
    10,735724.547222222,735724.579861111,735724.604166667,13;
    11,735724.549305556,735724.588194444,735724.614583333,8;
    12,735724.563888889,735724.618055556,735724.645138889,42];

% we only care about IDs 1-26
employees_to_check= 1:26

for i= 1:length(data_matrix)
    %employee id is the fifth element
    this_employee = [data_matrix(i,5)];

    keep_record = ismember(this_row_tech, employees_to_check);

    if keep_record
       times_to_add = [data_matrix(i,2), data_matrix(i,3), data_matrix(i,4)]
       % save it someplace
    end 

end
```

What's a good approach for saving data like this?

Comment: There are a few options. You could use a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) with columns for ID and the `datetime` arrays. You could use a [map container](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) where the key is the ID and the value the `datetime` array. You could use a [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) with [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) but with strictly numeric IDs it's not the nicest option.

Comment: Of those, `table` is probably the 'best' if you're looking to run statistics since it has methods to group and operate over variables in the table. One caveat: though it's been improving since it was introduced a couple years ago, `table`'s methods may still be slower than operating with the 'raw' data classes on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example of how to use tables in your case:

```
dataTable = array2table(data_matrix,'VariableNames',...
    {'serial','time1','time2','time3','employeeID'});
dataTable.time1 = datetime(datestr(dataTable.time1));
dataTable.time2 = datetime(datestr(dataTable.time2));
dataTable.time3 = datetime(datestr(dataTable.time3));

% we only care about IDs 1-26
valid = dataTable.employeeID>=1 & dataTable.employeeID<=26;
employees_to_check = dataTable(valid,:);
times_to_add = employees_to_check{:,2:4};
```

So your table `dataTable` looks like:

```
dataTable = 
    serial           time1                   time2                   time3            employeeID
    ______    ____________________    ____________________    ____________________    __________
     1        05-May-2014 07:00:00    05-May-2014 07:45:00    05-May-2014 08:15:00     5        
     2        05-May-2014 07:57:00    05-May-2014 08:10:00    05-May-2014 08:55:00    18        
     3        05-May-2014 09:39:00    05-May-2014 10:06:00    05-May-2014 10:42:00    18        
     4        05-May-2014 09:52:00    05-May-2014 11:10:00    05-May-2014 12:23:00    42        
     5        05-May-2014 09:54:00    05-May-2014 10:24:00    05-May-2014 11:01:00     8        
     6        05-May-2014 10:12:00    05-May-2014 12:28:00    05-May-2014 13:16:00     5        
     7        05-May-2014 10:21:00    05-May-2014 10:56:00    05-May-2014 11:35:00    18        
     8        05-May-2014 10:32:00    05-May-2014 11:41:00    05-May-2014 11:54:00     8        
     9        05-May-2014 12:46:00    05-May-2014 13:05:00    05-May-2014 13:57:00    18        
    10        05-May-2014 13:08:00    05-May-2014 13:55:00    05-May-2014 14:30:00    13        
    11        05-May-2014 13:11:00    05-May-2014 14:07:00    05-May-2014 14:45:00     8        
    12        05-May-2014 13:32:00    05-May-2014 14:50:00    05-May-2014 15:29:00    42
```

and the output is:

```
times_to_add = 
   05-May-2014 07:00:00   05-May-2014 07:45:00   05-May-2014 08:15:00
   05-May-2014 07:57:00   05-May-2014 08:10:00   05-May-2014 08:55:00
   05-May-2014 09:39:00   05-May-2014 10:06:00   05-May-2014 10:42:00
   05-May-2014 09:54:00   05-May-2014 10:24:00   05-May-2014 11:01:00
   05-May-2014 10:12:00   05-May-2014 12:28:00   05-May-2014 13:16:00
   05-May-2014 10:21:00   05-May-2014 10:56:00   05-May-2014 11:35:00
   05-May-2014 10:32:00   05-May-2014 11:41:00   05-May-2014 11:54:00
   05-May-2014 12:46:00   05-May-2014 13:05:00   05-May-2014 13:57:00
   05-May-2014 13:08:00   05-May-2014 13:55:00   05-May-2014 14:30:00
   05-May-2014 13:11:00   05-May-2014 14:07:00   05-May-2014 14:45:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!  I've been sifting through a bunch of table documentation from the earlier comment and this is a HUGE help- I'll try it right now!

Comment: This was perfect!  It let me move on to the fun stuff (being able to loop through the valid employees, check their times, and report which has the biggest bias)- thank you for getting me through the ugly part!

Comment: You welcome, just notice a little correction: `dataTable.employeeID>=1` I forgot the `=` before, now the answer is corrected.